# Why does Highcharts <div> element take up the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to embed a small chart (using Highcharts) on my webpage. I've provided an example of what I'm trying to do. When the page loads, the chart takes up the entire page by overwriting whats in the mainDiv (which I haven't included in here). I've tried modifying the dimensions of the division and the chart. I've also looked at the 'renderTo' parameter for 'chart', and tried rendering it as an object reference.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Am I missing a critical parameter in my chart? Or have I written my code incorrectly? Thanks.

```
<!-- mainDiv is what's getting overwritten -->
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
<div id="container" style="width:10px; height:10px;"></div>

<script>
    $(function () { 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are there any stylesheets being loaded on your site?

Comment: Setting an elements size has no meaning whitout a position other than static.

Comment: No stylesheets are being loaded. I'm trying to do it as simply as possible until I can sort out this error.

Comment: `<div id="container" style="width:10px; height:10px; position: relative;"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the id attribute of my  element from "container" to just "contain" (and obviously changed any code that previously referenced "container" to just reference "contain").

For whatever reason this fixed my problem, although I'm still not quite sure why. Perhaps "container" is a keyword used by Highcharts.

Final code looked like this:

```
<!-- mainDiv is what's getting overwritten -->
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
<div id="contain" style="width:10px; height:10px;"></div>

<script>
    $(function () { 
        $('#contain').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, I've spent the last few days working with Highcharts code and haven't run into any problems with my solution.

Comment: I had this same issue and I know exactly why it was happening.

The tutorial from   [1]: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart assumes that you are starting from a completely blank HTML page. In my case I was using a template generated by a Content Management System and there was already a `<div id="container">` previously in the DOM.

By changing the name of the ID in `<div>` element to one that did not already exist the chart behaved as expected instead of overriding the previous DOM element which in my case was a wrapper just inside the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but have you tried the renderTo: 'divname' option... Something like...

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
```

Comment: I did try this. I actually just figured out what the problem was, and I am able to incorporate the renderTo parameter into my code as well. It doesn't seem to make a difference if I use this or not though.